# Can't find method DragMove

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I am implementing a drag and drop, and for that i need to (seen in an example) do :
this.DragMove();

but this gives me an error. Do i have to add a reference or something to solve this problem?

Comment: What are you trying to drag..Which example are you following..? Some code might be helpful

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=22855

I used this example...

Answer (score 0):

Which Framework version are you using..? Are you able to do dragdrop in the sample application provided ?
[DragMove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dragmove.aspx) is a method in the System.Windows namespace.Are you sure that you are calling this method in a window ? Please post the code that is throwing the error

**EDIT**

If you are trying to drag across two itemscontrols consider using this free library

http://code.google.com/p/gong-wpf-dragdrop/

You can get a fair overview from Bea's article from the link below

http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53

Comment: I've got the problem. I used this method in an user control. So of course it didn't word. Pretty stupid. But now my question: I have to use dragmove(), but in a user control. Somebody who can help me out in some way?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to drag a control. The `DragMove` method is only declared in the `Window` class, it won't work for other controls.